# What should I use in this query to replace GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

Im with a little issue, i wanted to replace the  `GROUP BY pid`  here but I dont know what should I use.. Here is my query

```
SELECT `s`.`name` `server_name`, 
       `g`.`name` `group_name`, 
       `a`.`pid`  `pid` 
FROM   `panel_admins` `a` 
       LEFT JOIN `panel_players` `p` 
              ON `a`.`pid` = `p`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `panel_admin_groups` `g` 
              ON `a`.`gid` = `g`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT `username`, 
                         `pid` 
                  FROM   `panel_players_username` 
                  GROUP  BY `pid` 
                  ORDER  BY `last_used` DESC) `u` 
              ON `a`.`pid` = `u`.`pid` 
       LEFT JOIN `panel_servers` `s` 
              ON `a`.`sid` = `s`.`id` 
WHERE  ( Timestampdiff(minute, add_time, Now()) < `g`.`usetime` 
          OR `g`.`usetime` = 0 ) 
ORDER  BY `immunity` DESC;
```

My MySQL tables:
From panel_admins table I have this:

```
aid     pid     sid    gid   add_time   
--------------------------------------------------------------
 5      168     12     10   2018-08-13 18:05:36
 6      168     11     10   2018-08-13 18:05:36
```

In panel_players:

```
id(that corresponds to pid)     steamid     country
----------------------------------------------------
168                           steamidhere       EN
```

In panel_players_username:

```
pid     username     connections      last_used
----------------------------------------------------
168     peter          21            2018-08-13 17:50:26
```

And in panel_servers:

```
id(that corresponds to sid)     name        ip        port         rcon_pw
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
10                           surfcombat     IPHERE     PORTHERE    RCONHERE
11                           jailbreak      IPHERE     PORTHERE    RCONHERE
12                           executes       IPHERE     PORTHERE    RCONHERE
```

I want to replace GROUP BY in this query because my web hosting doesent allow me to use this `GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

> I already try to disable it, but im using payed webhosting with
>   CPanel and I need more privileges to activate it..

Comment: Could you provide some smaple data and expect result? the `group by` make no sense because   You didn't use  any aggregate function

Comment: We have a query that obviously doesn't do what you want and a request to "replace `GROUP BY`". But we have no idea *what you're trying to do*. Please [edit] your question, and add some *explanation*, as well as the sample data and expected results that D-Shih mentions.

Comment: Make it easy to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: `... (SELECT username, pid FROM panel_players_username ORDER  BY last_used DESC LIMIT 1) ...`

Comment: Added some info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behaviour when you underspecify an aggregate query on older versions of [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) was that it would [retrieve data from an *unspecified* row](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) within the group for any non-grouped and non-aggregated columns. This was usually less than desirable, but because it "worked", many mysql developers never stopped to think about it:

> Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause.

Now, it wants you to be specific. E.g.

```
              SELECT MIN(`username`), 
                     `pid` 
              FROM   `panel_players_username` 
              GROUP  BY `pid`
```

Where we're now being forced to tell mysql *which value* to select for the ungrouped column. Here I've picked `MIN`. Of course, `MAX` could be right, or even something else. But at least now, you have to *think about* your data, and if there are multiple usernames associated with a single `pid`, what do you actually *want to do about it*?

Please don't try to disable `sql_mode=only_full_group_by`. It's saving you from overlooking data issues.

Comment: With that part I keep getting that message to disable sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: @Peter - so you've wrapped `username` in the select clause with `MIN`, as I've shown above? (I've just noticed that `ORDER BY` as well, that's generally pointless here so remove that too)

Comment: Well it doesent give me errors, but it is not giving the output I wanted

Comment: @Peter - given your sample data only contains one row in `panel_players_username`, it's difficult to know what you do want. Note that I've highlighted/quoted the part of the documentation that points out the under older mysql versions, that `ORDER BY` clause was *not* controlling which `username` value would be selected within each `GROUP`, so if you were in the habit of writing such code and expecting such influence, it was never safe.

Comment: @Peter - I've just re-read your query. It doesn't use `username` outside of this query. Now I'm really stumped on what you're trying to do here.

Comment: Im trying to make an alternative to GROUP ID because the webhosting doesent let me use my current query because of this sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: No, you're allowed to use `GROUP BY`, and that's what I'm doing above. But you're forced to write `GROUP BY` now in a manner that *makes sense*.

Comment: Thank you for all the clarification.